# Optimizer for IntelliJ IDEA- changes are not persistent

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using Optimizer for IntelliJ IDEA (https://zeroturnaround.com/free/optimizer-for-intellij-idea). I click buttons

- tune jvm options
- disable verification

and restart IDEA. Upon restart, Optimizer windows comes again and advises the very same optimizations.  He claims

> 'class verification is enabled', 'JVM options are not optimal.'

It looks like that proposed optimizations were not persisted.

How can I make sure that optimizations are correctly and persistently applied?

> IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3
>   Build #IC-163.7743.44, built on November 17, 2016
>   JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-b555 amd64
>   JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by
>   JetBrains s.r.o

I had same problem in previous versions (2016.2 and 2016.1). 
I also had same problem with Oracle JDK (java8, 64 bit).
I work on Windows 7. I work on non-admin account, with UAC enabled.
I have no UAC popups when I use optimizer or start IntelliJ .